# App crashes when using two setText instead of one

Tags: java, android

Not sure why this is happening when I added this line it started crashing the app:

```
    total = total + add;
    tvMoney.setText("Your Total is $" + total);
```

Here is the full section of code and when I remove (or comment out) the above code it works fine. The app is supposed to update one section while also updating another text that has the overall total.

```
// What happens when the "+" button is pressed.
public void sendAdd(View view) {
    llMoney = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llMoney);
    etMoney = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMoney);
    String message = etMoney.getText().toString();
    if (message == null || message.isEmpty()){
        add = 0.0;
    } else {
        add = Double.parseDouble(etMoney.getText().toString());
    }

    total = total + add;
    tvMoney.setText("Your Total is $" + total);     

    TextView text = new TextView(this);
    text.setText("You've added money! + " + message);
    text.setTextSize(20);
    text.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    text.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    llMoney.addView(text);
```

---

Here is the declaration of variables:

```
//declaring items
LinearLayout llNotes, llMoney;
Button butNotes, butAdd, butSub;
EditText etNotes, etMoney;
TextView tvMoney;

//To update the total amount of money variable
double total, add, sub;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    total = 0.0;
    add = 0.0;
    sub = 0.0;
```

---

LOGCAT

```
05-11 17:54:20.477: D/AndroidRuntime(23918): Shutting down VM
05-11 17:54:20.477: W/dalvikvm(23918): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4145c360)
05-11 17:54:20.497: E/AndroidRuntime(23918): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 17:54:20.497: E/AndroidRuntime(23918): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-11 17:54:20.497: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3690)
05-11 17:54:20.497: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4192)
05-11 17:54:20.497: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17254)
05-11 17:54:20.497: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-11 17:54:20.497: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-11 17:54:20.497: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-11 17:54:20.497: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
05-11 17:54:20.497: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 17:54:20.497: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-11 17:54:20.497: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
05-11 17:54:20.497: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
05-11 17:54:20.497: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-11 17:54:20.497: E/AndroidRuntime(23918): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-11 17:54:20.497: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 17:54:20.497: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-11 17:54:20.497: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3685)
05-11 17:54:20.497: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    ... 11 more
05-11 17:54:20.497: E/AndroidRuntime(23918): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-11 17:54:20.497: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at net.tagyoureit.heykeepup.MainActivity.sendAdd(MainActivity.java:123)
05-11 17:54:20.497: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: tvMoney is declared and initialized where? What is in the logcat?

Comment: also where is total defined?

Comment: I didn't add the entire class. The double total is declared in the class, and is set to 0.0 on onCreate.

Comment: I've also added the logcat

Comment: Posted an answer, but on a side note, if you're using an IDE to code, then learn how to debug with it. Breakpoints, stepping through code, and variable watchlists. This will allow you to tell if it's null, and where the actual exception is. Once you saw it as null, you could have figured it wasn't actually instantiated anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't appear to be instantiating your tvMoney variable anywhere, like this:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

tvMoney = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMoney);

total = 0.0;
add = 0.0;
sub = 0.0;
```

Comment: Oh my god... I feel so stupid. This was it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're not initializeing tvMoney.

If you don't initialize a member variable (like tvMoney) your code will compile, but you'll have problems at runtime.

Comment: I've added an edit to the post to show what I did with those variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
when I added this line it started crashing the app:
```

`tvMoney` is null when your trying to set a text . You need to find the instance of the `TextView` before accessing it. i believe you have a `TextView` id as `tvMoney` in `Activity layout` , then change it

```
tvMoney = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvMoney);

tvMoney.setText("Your Total is $" + total);
```

Comment: Yep, I'm an idiot... sorry I've apparently been at this too long today.